# Получить список жанров из базы в аксессе

Tags: база-данных, access

Добрый день, господа. Сейчас делаю курсовую работу, но, к сожалению, не могу разобраться с одним моментом. У меня есть база данных в аксессе. Есть форма, на которой находятся две дочерние по отношению к ней, которые берут данные из одной таблицы, содержащей название песни и жанр. Записей (жанров) для одной песни может быть много. При выборе определенной песни в первой подформе, во второй должны отображаться все записи, а точнее, только список жанров, с этим же названием. Я составила следующий запрос:

> SELECT Жанр FROM [Список песен] WHERE Название = songName

, где songName = Me!Название.Text

Однако, я не могу разобраться, как передать полученный список жанров во вторую подформу. Я пробовала несколько вариантов, но постоянно выводилось сообщение о том, что введенное выражение содержит недопустимую ссылку на свойство Form. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно отобразить его

Comment: Ты пробовал считывать список запросом в RecordSet, а его передавать на следующую форму? Можно попробовать RecordSet считать в массив и его передавать.

Comment: У меня проблемы именно с передачей моего запроса в RecordSource второй дочерней формы с жанрами. Не понимаю, как это можно сделать. Пробовала передавать через Parent (что-то вроде Me!Parent![Жанры].Form.RecordSource), и еще несколькими способами, но постоянно выскакивала ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Recordsource для второй подчиненной формы должно быть что-то вроде этого:

```
SELECT Жанр FROM [Список песен] WHERE Название = Forms![Главная Форма]![Жанры].Form![Название]
```

И добавить Requery второй подчиненной формы в событие Current первой

Также можно сделать вообще без кода, если сделать второй уровень вложенности подформ со встроенной возможностью связи мастера с подчиненной формой. Т.е. сначала рисуем форму для песен с подчиненной формой жанров, а затем эту форму вставляем в качесве подформы в вашу главную форму, связывая подформы через свойства Link Master Fields и Link Child Fields (сорри, нет русской версии под рукой)